# Rabbit consumer stops consuming after channel.basic.ack

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, amqpstorm

I use python 3 and amqpstorm package. I have this piece of code (abbreviated) working with open rabbitmq connection:

```
ichannel = connection.channel(rpc_timeout = 5)
ichannel.basic.qos(10000)
ichannel.queue.bind(...)
ichannel.basic.consume(self.<process_message>, <queue>, no_ack = False)
ichannel.start_consuming(to_tuple = False)
```

I process these 10000 messages in a batch after receiving the last one and when I call within process_message function:

```
ichannel.basic.ack(0, True)
```

to acknowledge all 10000 messages. Function **start_consuming** finishes. Does anybody know why, please? I would like to continue receiving messages after this multiply acknoledgement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by passing a real delivery tag of the last message instead generally 0 (which should behave in the same way - but it doesn't...) to basic.ack function.

Comment: Thanks - this is fixed in the next release https://github.com/eandersson/amqpstorm/issues/47